# shuffled_data = data[shuffle_indices] IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, sentiment-analysis

def batch_iter(data, batch_size, num_epochs):

```
"""
Generates a batch iterator for a dataset.
"""
data = np.array(data)
data_size = len(str(data))
num_batches_per_epoch = int(len(str(data))/batch_size) + 1
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Shuffle the data at each epoch
    shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(data_size))
    shuffled_data = data[shuffle_indices]
    for batch_num in range(num_batches_per_epoch):
        start_index = batch_num * batch_size
        end_index = min((batch_num + 1) * batch_size, data_size)
        yield shuffled_data[start_index:end_index]
```

**ERROR** 
Data processing OK, creating network...

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "twitter-sentiment-cnn.py", line 299, in

```
test_batches = list(batch_iter(zip(x_test, y_test), FLAGS.batch_size, 1))
```

File "/home/bizviz/Desktop/twitter-sentiment-cnn/data_helpers.py", line 183, in batch_iter

```
shuffled_data = data[shuffle_indices]
```

**IndexError: too many indices for array**

I am not understanting why i got this error, its not in 1D, kindly help me with this question please.

Comment: What's `data`? (shape, str / int / float...) Can you provide a sample so we can run the code?

Comment: this is a function for running iteration of batches, the full code is very big and another file containing all the tokenized words and test, train data, flags etc.

Comment: Without knowing how data looks like, we can't answer your question. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `data` doesn't have to be your real data but at least part of it (which represent the structure of it)

Comment: https://github.com/danielegrattarola/twitter-sentiment-cnn/blob/master/twitter-sentiment-cnn.py

Comment: data is basic tokenized data.
shuffled_indices output is [20 1 2  3 6 4 8 13 12 15 9 10 5 11 14 7 17 16 19 18]